# Show $P(A|B) > P(A|B^c)$ is equivalent to $P(B|A) > P(B|A^c)$

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

This is a problem from Blitzstein and Hwang Introduction to Probability.

> Consider the following scenario, from Tversky and Kahneman [30]:  Let
>   A be the event that before the end of next year, Peter will have
>   installed  a burglar alarm system in his home. Let B denote the event
>   that Peter’s  home will be burglarized before the end of next year.
>
> (c) Show that for any events $A$ and $B$ (with probabilities not equal to
>   0 or 1), $P(A|B) >  P(A|B^c )$ is equivalent to $P(B|A) > P(B|A^c)$.
>
> Blitzstein, Joseph K.. Introduction to Probability (Chapman & Hall/CRC
>   Texts in Statistical Science) (p. 76). Chapman and Hall/CRC. Kindle
>   Edition.

Using Bayes:
$$
\frac{P(A|B)}{P(A|B^c)}=\frac{P(B|A)P(B^c)}{P(B^c|A)P(B)}
$$

Not sure how to go beyond this step.

Comment: What have you tried?  Bayes theorem is pretty straightforward...

Comment: @nomen Added as far as I could get with Bayes.

Answer (score 3):

Let
 $$a = P(A^c \cap B)$$
 $$b = P(A \cap B)$$
 $$c = P(A \cap B^c)$$
$$d =  P(A^c \cap B^c)$$
These denote the 4 regions of the Venn Diagram for events $A$ and $B$.

By assumption :
$$P(A|B) > P(A|B^c) \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} > \frac{P(A \cap B^c)}{P(B^c)}$$ 
We substitute to get 
$$\frac{b}{a+b} > \frac{c}{c+d}$$
We multiply by the denominators, and simplify to get
$$bd > ac \Leftrightarrow$$
$$ab + bd > ab + ac \Leftrightarrow$$
$$b(a+d) > a(b+c) \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{b}{b+c} > \frac{a}{a+d}$$
Substitue back to get
$$\frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)} > \frac{ P(B \cap A^c)}{P(A^c)} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$P(B|A) > P(B|A^c)$$

Comment: Quick question. In your first lemma shouldn't it be $P(X)=P(X|Y)P(Y)+P(X|Y^c)P(Y^c)$?

Comment: Absolutely. I'll edit that out...

Comment: makes it harder to solve! ;)

Comment: Alright. Round 2 should be good!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that

$$P(B)+P(B^c)\frac{P(A|B^c)}{P(A|B)}=\frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(A\cap B)}=P(A)+P(A^c)\frac{P(B|A^c)}{P(B|A)}$$